# Use FolderBrowserDialog in asp.net WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net Web Application. I want to select Folder and upload all files in that selected folder. For that i have used FolderBrowserDialog control. This is my code

```
FolderBrowserDialog fi = new FolderBrowserDialog();

DialogResult result = fi.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string foldername = fi.SelectedPath;
    foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(foldername))
    {
        string asfas = filename;
    }
}
```

but it gives error `Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.`

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1390665.aspx that Windows apps and Web Apps are a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should add [MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
MessageBox.Show(message, "test", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error,     
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);
```